# Python: How to split dataframe with datetime index by number of observations?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {
  'aapl': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
  'aal' : [33, 33, 33, 32, 31, 30, 34, 29, 27, 26],
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.index = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-01-10')

n_obs = len(data) * 0.3
train, test = data[:n_obs], data[n_obs:]
```

`>>> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [3.0] of type float`

I can probably slice the dataframe by date like `df[ : '2011-01-05' ]`, but I want to be splitting the data by number of observations, which I have difficulties using the method above.

Comment: you need to provide a minimal reproducible sample of the DataFrame, and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway Sorry about that. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure having an integer for slicing:

```
n_obs = int(len(data) * 0.3)
train, test = data[:n_obs], data[n_obs:]
```

output:

```
# train
            aapl  aal
2011-01-01    11   33
2011-01-02    12   33
2011-01-03    13   33

# test
            aapl  aal
2011-01-04    14   32
2011-01-05    15   31
2011-01-06    16   30
2011-01-07    17   34
2011-01-08    18   29
2011-01-09    19   27
2011-01-10    20   26
```

If you want to train/test a model you might be interested in getting a random [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
test = data.sample(frac=0.3)
train = data.loc[data.index.difference(test.index)]
```